# Menu to add a number?

Tags: python, menu

Im trying to create a menu in Python and one of the options is to "Add a number to the list/array". This is what I have but I cant figure out why it isn't running. Thank you!

```
def addOne (num):
    while True:
        try:       
            num = (int(input("Give me a number:"))
            if num < 0:
                raise exception

            print("Thank you!")
        break
        except:
            print("Invalid. Try again...")
        num.sort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors:

1. You are missing a `)` at the end of the line assigning to `num`
2. you can't `raise exception` - it should be `Exception`
3. The `break` is missing an indentation.

In addition this line is instead assigning an `int` to the `num` and not adding and item.

```
num = (int(input("Give me a number:"))
```

And then the `sort()` will fail because an integer does not have `sort` function. Instead:

```
num.append(int(input("Give me a number:")))
```

Comment: num is a collection, every time I run it it says invalid syntax referring to the semicolon after if  (num < 0):